# How to avoid overwriting the data from a list to a dictionary using for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary as follows:

```
bus = dict()
pvsystem = dict()
    for j in range(500):
        bus[j] = {'vm': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, 'va': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}}
    nw = dict()
    for step in range(24):
        c = step + 1
        nw[str(c)] = {'bus': bus}
    solution = {'nw': nw}
    results = {'solution': solution}
```

I am using a for loop to fill up the values in the nested dictionary as follows:

```
for step in range(10):
    c = step + 1
    for b in range(20):
        AllpuVmVa = dss.Bus.puVmagAngle()
        results['solution']['nw'][str(c)]['bus'][b]["vm"]['a'] = AllpuVmVa[0]
        results['solution']['nw'][str(c)]['bus'][b]["va"]['a'] = AllpuVmVa[1]
    print("Step: ", c, " Voltages: ", AllpuVmVa)
```

`AllpuVmVa` is a list. Its values are changed once the step changed (It is defined based on function outside the loop).

Here, using the `print` function, it is clear that the values of `AllpuVmVa` at each step are different, but the values stored in (`results['solution']['nw'][str(c)]['bus'][b]["vm"]['a']`) and (`results['solution']['nw'][str(c)]['bus'][b]["va"]['a']`) are the same for all the steps, which is equal to the last step. It sounds that there is overwriting for the data.

Is there any idea to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you assign the same dictionary stored in `bus` to every value in `nw` dict. To fix the issue, you can make new `bus` dictionary every iteration. For example:

```
bus = dict()
pvsystem = dict()

def get_bus():
    return {j: {'vm': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}, 'va': {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}} for j in range(500)}

nw = dict()
for step in range(24):
    c = step + 1
    nw[str(c)] = {'bus': get_bus()}     # <-- use get_bus() here

solution = {'nw': nw}
results = {'solution': solution}
```